# Make Django DB Transaction Idempotent on an External Call

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

I'm using a Django DB with a Postgres backend. Each user has a "balance" associated with their DB object, which is their current funds in the system. They can cash out the balance via gift cards, which is done by sending a POST request to Amazon's API.

I perform two operations when the cash out their balance:

- Update the DB to set their balance to 0
- Send a POST request to the Amazon API to generate a gift card for their balance

If only one of these operations happen, that's very bad, for obvious reasons. I know you can use Transactions to make sure multiple database operations happen atomically -- is there a way to do something similar with a DB operation and an external call like this?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: it gets complicated. You need to record the fact that you are sending a POST when you deduct the cost of the gift card. Then you need to have a system in place in case the POST doesn't happen or fails or Amazon goes bust, or... Or you do it the other way around and don't deduct until you get confirmation from Amazon and deal with that nit happening. There's no magic solution to bind together different systems on opposite sides of the world.

Comment: https://dev.to/ck3130/idempotence-and-post-requests-in-django-2bbf